# Get value of bean in view.list.php

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I used suiteCRM v7.1.5

I want to know how can I get the values of `$bean` in view.list.php file.
I did this code, to hide checkbox and edit_btn for all signed contracts:

[view.list.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpn0r.png) file

And the result is `BEFORE IF AFTER IF`, because I cannot get the value of `STATUS_CTR (SIGNED / UNSIGNED) $this->bean->statut_ctr_c`

Answer (score 0):

On the list view there can be multiple records so there is no singular bean that will do the trick for you. A way to do this is to use the [process_record](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.7/Module_Framework/Logic_Hooks/Module_Hooks/process_record/index.html) logic hook. This gets triggered for every row on the list view and you can access the data there.

Comment: Thank u MR EGG for ur replay, but my final need is this :
https://suitecrm.com/forum/suitecrm-7-0-discussion/6835-remove-checkbox-from-list-view

so i created one logic hook like that :